# Regular expression matches the second entry only

Tags: python, regex

I need a regular expression that will match all individual entrepreneurs' names. So, I wrote the next:

```
((?i)индивидуальный предприниматель|ип) [А-Я][а-я]+ [А-Я](\.|[а-я]+) [А-Я](\.|[а-я]+)
```

In text:

> Индивидуальный предприниматель Шаладко Пётр Владиславович, именуемый в
>   дальнейшем "Арендодатель". и индивидуальный предприниматель Сергеев
>   Денис Александрович, действующий на основании Свидетельства, именуемый
>   в дальнейшем "Арендатор", заключили настоящий договор о нижеследующем:

My expression matches one entry only:

> индивидуальный предприниматель Сергеев Денис Александрович

ignoring

> Индивидуальный предприниматель Шаладко Пётр Владиславович

Why does it happen? Where did I miss?

Comment: Are you sure that regex ranges work as you expect with the Cyrillic alphabet?  You should check on that first.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, yes, it works but Ё as I've known from the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Russian alphabet contains 33 letters and one of them, `ё` / `Ё`, does not fall into the `а-я` and `А-Я` ranges. Add them to the character classes:

```
(?i)(?:индивидуальный предприниматель|ип) [А-ЯЁ][а-яё]+ [А-ЯЁ](?:\.|[а-яё]+) [А-ЯЁ](?:\.|[а-яё]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hvAihM/1). I am also using non-capturing groups to extract full matches only with `re.findall`.

If you need to extract the names only, wrap that part of the regex pattern with a capturing group (`([А-ЯЁ][а-яё]+ [А-ЯЁ](?:\.|[а-яё]+) [А-ЯЁ](?:\.|[а-яё]+))`):

```
re.findall(r'(?i)(?:индивидуальный предприниматель|ип) ([А-ЯЁ][а-яё]+ [А-ЯЁ](?:\.|[а-яё]+) [А-ЯЁ](?:\.|[а-яё]+))', text)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hvAihM/2)

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/UX72uw):

```
import re
text = 'Индивидуальный предприниматель Шаладко Пётр Владиславович, именуемый в дальнейшем "Арендодатель". и индивидуальный предприниматель Сергеев Денис Александрович, действующий на основании Свидетельства, именуемый в дальнейшем "Арендатор", заключили настоящий договор о нижеследующем:'
rx = re.compile(r'(?:индивидуальный предприниматель|ип) ([А-ЯЁ][а-яё]+ [А-ЯЁ](?:\.|[а-яё]+) [А-ЯЁ](?:\.|[а-яё]+))', re.I)
print(rx.findall(text))
```

Output: `['Шаладко Пётр Владиславович', 'Сергеев Денис Александрович']`